# How to make help images when a cordova app start

Tags: jquery, image, cordova

I'm wondering how that images (9-patch i guess) are created and putted in the begin of a mobile app and give some help for the user, how to use that app. I have create an app with cordova and i want to know if there is a plugin to do that or some jquery code for slideshow.

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. If you have created a cordova app, its based on html5 and including images are simply a case of html img tags or css or both. Are you asking about a startup image? Like what we call a splash page?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! No i dont ask for the splash screen which has a plugin to show. I ask for those images which show after splash screen (they may be 3, 4 or more) and present some help for the user on how to use the app. Like this image https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9pwaS88VwkmaVBQMDdNa014M3E2ZGJndmM0YkpsN2tlNG4w/view which has a continue button in the middle and when you press it, it shows an other image with directions for the app use. Is It only a full screen slideshow with HTML5 or something more like a plug in? I just want to help my "clients" on how to use my app...